# Access denied issue for Microsoft graph api

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When I share excel url with personal one drive account and doing get request of URL details with office account token I have an issue when using shared url from personal drive which has the format

```
https://1drv.ms/x/s!{token}
```

or

```
https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=B4FDB33875A82&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!EKQJrE3T5A
```

Permissions Scopes I have given as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#encoding-sharing-urls)

Request :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}/driveItem
```

Response :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "The sharing link no longer exists, or you do not have permission to access it.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-06-29T12:49:15",
            "request-id": "e1e9f673-1b66-49f3-8abd-70a1240f5442",
            "client-request-id": "e1e9f673-1b66-49f3-8abd-70a1240f5442"
        }
    }
}
```